How does model choice impact the results of "Optimize this Code" with Continue and VS Code
According to the Continue documentation at https://docs.continue.dev/setup/select-model, with Ollama as a provider, I can specify a main model for chat, an autocomplete model and a model for embeddings.
I am using llama3:8b for chat, starcoder2:3b for autocomplete and nomic-embed-text:137m for embedings.  Unfortunately I don't have the processing power to switch to llama:70b and am unsure what would be a better model. I can use starcoder2:7b or a different embeddings model.
My question, which I haven't been able to answer from reading the Continue docs or through limited web research, is which of the three models has the largest impact on the performance of "Optimize your Code".  It is an option in the Continue sub-menu that's available when I highlight code and right click.
